# Limit of the the function ln with log without using L'Hopital Rule

Tags: calculus

I have tried to solve it conjugate but doesn't work, Could you find another way?

\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to 2} \left(\frac{e^{x+1}-e^3}{\ln(x)-\ln (2)}\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: Please do not list out *multiple problems* and *show no work* and still expect us to provide answers.  We expect you to show us what you have tried, even if you don't believe it works.

Comment: the second Limit should be $$\frac{1}{9\ln(3)}$$

Comment: I agree with you but I was asked and didn't  have time.

Comment: I'd basically use Cauchy's theorem once per instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{e^{x+1}-e^{3}}{\log(x)-\log 2} = \lim_{x\to 2}\frac{e^{x+1}-e^{3}}{x-2}\cdot\frac{x-2}{\log(x)-\log 2}$$
but:
$$ \lim_{x\to 2}\frac{e^{x+1}-e^{3}}{x-2} = e\cdot \lim_{x\to 2}\frac{e^{x}-e^{2}}{x-2} = e^3\cdot\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{e^z-1}{z} = e^3 $$
and:
$$ \lim_{x\to 2}\frac{x-2}{\log(x)-\log(2)}=\lim_{z\to 1}\frac{2z-2}{\log(z)}=2\cdot\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{e^t-1}{t} = 2$$
so the original limit is solved through simple substitutions and the Lemma $\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{e^u-1}{u}=1$.
The same approach works in the second case, too.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to note that these limits can be evaluated using the definition of the respective derivatives
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{e^{x+1}-e^{3}}{\ln x-\ln 2} &= \lim_{x\to 2}\frac{e^{x+1}-e^{3}}{x-2}\cdot\frac{x-2}{\ln x-\ln 2} \\
&= \lim_{x\to 2}\frac{e^{x+1}-e^{3}}{x-2}\cdot \lim_{x\to 2}\frac{x-2}{\ln x-\ln 2} \text{ assuming both limits exist}\\
& = (e^{x+1})'|_{x=2} \div (\ln x)'|_{x=2} \\
&= e^3 \cdot 2
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 9} \frac{\log_3{x}-2}{x-9} &= \left(\log_3{x}\right)'|_{x=9} \\
&= \frac{1}{\ln 3}\frac{1}{x}\bigg\vert_{x=9} \\
&= \frac{1}{9\ln(3)}
\end{align}

Comment: In the first problem, aren't you using L'hôpital's rule, just more sneakily?

Comment: No.  I don't believe so.  Only the definition of derivative is used.  I believe introducing the factor of $x-2$ and splitting the limits is going to be necessary in any solution not involving L'Hôpital's Rule.